# In Perl, how can I strip spaces from a string except in double-quotes, and replace those quotation marks with ||?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to find a way to replace spaces and double quotes with pipes (||) while leaving the spaces within the double quotes untouched.

For example, it would make something like 'word "word word" word' into 'word||word word||word' and another like 'word word word' into 'word||word||word'.

Right now I have this to work off of:

```
[%- MACRO typestrip(value) PERL -%]
my $htmlVal = $stash->get('value');
$htmlVal =~ s/"/||/g;
print $htmlVal
[%- END -%]
```

Which handles replacing double quotes with pipes just fine.

I don't know how simple or complex this should be or if it can even be done, since I have no actual background in programming and, while I have worked with some Perl, it's never been this kind before, so I apologize if I'm not doing a good job of explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems possible and might be useful if only a regex is applicable:

```
 $htmlVal =~ s/(?:"([^"]+)"(\s*))|(?:(\S+)(\s*))/($1||$3).($2||$4?'||':'')/eg;
```

(Might be beautified a bit after closer introspection.)

input:

```
 my $htmlVal ='word "word word" word';
```

output:

```
 word||word word||word
```

---

Original code has been modified after failing this case:

```
 my $htmlVal ='word "word word" "word word"';
```

will now work too:

```
 word||word word||word word
```

---

Explanation:

```
 $htmlVal =~ s/
               (?: " ([^"]+) " (\s*)) # search "abc abc" ($1), End ($2)
               |                      # OR
               (?: (\S+) (\s*))       # abcd ($3), End ($4)
              /
               ($1||$3) . ($2||$4 ? '||' : '') # decide on $1/$2 or $3/$4 
              /exg;
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: if it had this problem, there will be others. woudln't you rather use a parser?

Comment: @JoelBerger Yes, of course, sth. like this is not advisable for the average coder because he usually has no time to work this out. This is where it would be a responsible decision to use proven tech like a good parser. On the other side - he asked specifically for a regex - and he got one. I read the Friedl book (I bought all three as dead-tree versions) and just wanted to use the knowledge (Hey Jeffrey, are you here?) If you look at the /x-version of the regex, it seems easy enough to be probably of some general value (imho).

Comment: Yeah ... nooooo ... use `Text::ParseWords::shellwords` which is tailor made for this situation.

Answer (score 9):

I think it might be easier to use the core module [`Text::ParseWords`](http://p3rl.org/Text::ParseWords) to split on non-quoted whitespace, then rejoin the "words" with pipes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  print space2pipes($line); 
  print "\n";
}

sub space2pipes {
  my $line = shift;
  chomp $line;
  my @words = parse_line( qr/\s+/, 0, $line );
  return join '||', @words;
}

__DATA__
word "word word" word
word word word
```

Putting this into your templating engine is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is related to a frequently-asked question, [answered in section 4 of the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-split-a-[character]-delimited-string-except-when-inside-[character]?).

> #### How can I split a [character]-delimited string except when inside [character]?
>
> Several modules can handle this sort of parsing—[Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html), [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV), [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV_XS), and [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html), among others.
>
> Take the example case of trying to split a string that is comma-separated into its different fields. You can’t use `split(/,/)` because you shouldn’t split if the comma is inside quotes. For example, take a data line like this:
>
> ```
> SAR001,"","Cimetrix, Inc","Bob Smith","CAM",N,8,1,0,7,"Error, Core Dumped"
> ```
>
> Due to the restriction of the quotes, this is a fairly complex problem. Thankfully, we have Jeffrey Friedl, author of *Mastering Regular Expressions*, to handle these for us. He suggests (assuming your string is contained in `$text`):
>
> ```
> my @new = ();
> push(@new, $+) while $text =~ m{
>            # groups the phrase inside the quotes
>              "([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)",?
>            | ([^,]+),?
>            | ,
>      }gx;
> push(@new, undef) if substr($text,-1,1) eq ',';
> ```
>
> If you want to represent quotation marks inside a quotation-mark-delimited field, escape them with backslashes (*e.g.*, `"like \"this\""`).
>
> Alternatively, the [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) module (part of the standard Perl distribution) lets you say:
>
> ```
> use Text::ParseWords;
> @new = quotewords(",", 0, $text);
> ```
>
> For parsing or generating CSV, though, using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) rather than implementing it yourself is highly recommended; you’ll save yourself odd bugs popping up later by just using code which has already been tried and tested in production for years.

Adapting the technique to your situation gives

```
my $htmlVal = 'word "word word" word';

my @chunks;
push @chunks, $+ while $htmlVal =~ m{
    "([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)"
  | (\S+)
}gx;

$htmlVal = join "||", @chunks;
print $htmlVal, "\n";
```

Output:

```
word||word word||word
```

Looking back, it turns out that this is an application of Randal’s Rule, as dubbed in [Regular Expression Mastery](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide070.html) by Mark Dominus:

> ### Randal's Rule
>
> - Randal Schwartz (author of *Learning Perl* [and also a [Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)]) says:
>
> > Use capturing or `m//g` when you know what you want to keep.
> >
> > Use `split` when you know what you want to throw away.
>
> [image: Randal Schwartz]

In your situation, you know what you want to keep, so use `m//g` to hang on to the text within quotes or otherwise separated by whitespace.

Comment: an interesting read, but doesn't it just say, "do what Joel said"? :-)

Comment: Agreed. "Do what Joel said!" ;-) but I do appreciate `perlfaq` links because it reminds people what a treasure trove of information can be found there.

Comment: Hear Hear! Remember, when in doubt: `perldoc -q <searchterm>`. (In this case `perldoc -q split` worked nicely)

Answer (score 1):

While [Joel's answer is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11232786/100754), things can be simplified a bit by specifically using `shellwords` to tokenize lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords qw( shellwords );

my @strings = (
    'word "word word" word',
    'word "word word" "word word"',
);

@strings = map join('||', shellwords($_)), @strings;

use YAML;
print Dump \@strings;
```

Isn't that more readable than a bunch of regex-gobbledygook?

Comment: *Isn't that more readable than a bunch of regex-gobbledygook?* - No, it is comparable if you are familiar w/regular expressions ;-)

Comment: Ok fine, do what Sinan said. :-P

Comment: @JoelBerger This order is for the O.P., for Sinan, or for me?

Comment: @rubberboots, it was more of a joke, we do basically the same thing. His function (`shellwords`) is a special version of `parsewords` for using space as the separator.